# How to get the ongoing call phone number

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I start 'Activity' using 'startActivity(callintent)' and wait for some time. Then I need to stop the call with 'onReceive()'. In this 'onReceive()' method how can I get the existing ongoing call phone number?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String oldnumber = intent.getStringExtra(intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    String newphnumber="9999999999";
    if ((newphnumber1=null) &&(newphnumber!=oldnumber)) {
        String msg = "Intercepted outgoing call. Old :" + oldnumber + 
                     ", new :" + newPhNnumber;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "end call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
            show();
        setResultData(newphnumber);
    }
}
```

Here `oldnumber` means already activated outgoing number (single call is going). How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

We can get the ongoing call number easily using BroadcastReceiver.
In your BroadcastReceiver class onReceive function you have to code like following,

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).toString();
            Log.w("", "Number---->"+number);
             Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and in your Activity class

```
MReciever mReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        mReceiver = new MReciever();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    };
```

And in your Android manifest file you have to declare your receiver as

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiverClass" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: in u r code number will get what? i explain my doubt. i did one call by startactivity(callintent). i have not dailed extra number. so only one call is outgoing.( that i called old number).to get that ongoing single phone number what i put to string oldnum= intent.action.?(extra will give if i dailed more than one number).

Comment: Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER means

A String holding the phone number originally entered in ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, or the actual number to call in a ACTION_CALL. 
Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER" .                refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)

Comment: @sateesh, sry, as u said that not give the result what i want. its not give  phone number. i tried that what u mentioned    is not giving the number/ resulting null value. do try and give exact one. if Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL,String number=intent.getStringExtra (Intent. EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER

Comment: @revan, When you run this application it returns only null value. but keep this application as in background and make a call in device on that time it shows the number

Comment: k, i will test this on real phone, and check it is printing null/number. thaks for u r reply.

Comment: hi @sateesh when i am trying to install my result .apk file into my phone its not installing, tel me what would be the reason.

Comment: Let me guess it as you have not metioned the error. You need to create a signed apk for it work in your phone. Did you try signed apk in your mobile or the one you used to debug in emulator. Link with details how to create signed apk. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing